# How to get data between two id's from mysql by using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to fetch rows between two id's (for example between 100 and 200). I have tried to fetch contents using datatable. Here `film_person` is my table, `person_id` is my primary key and I have tried to fetch values between 100 and 200, but the code throws an exception.

```
public static DataTable GetAllfilmperson()
{
    try
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;database=contentupload;uid=abcd;password=Abcd";
        string query = "SELECT * FROM `contentupload`.`film_person WHERE Person_id BETWEEN '100' AND '200' `";
        MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        ma.Fill(DS);

        return DS.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exception exactly?

Comment: @SonerGönül thank you for the reply, exceptions are getting different,i just want to know that my query is correct or not?

Comment: As long as you get exceptions, chances are, it's *not*.

Comment: What is the type of `Person_id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have characters in your statement that are either typos or at least mismatched. Remove them:

```
SELECT * FROM contentupload.film_person WHERE Person_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

Answer (score 2):

I *strongly* suspect your `Person_id` is numeric, that's why you don't need to use single quotes for numeric values.

```
WHERE Person_id BETWEEN '100' AND '200'
```

should be

```
WHERE Person_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200
```

And you have unnecessary [Grave Accent](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0060/index.htm) (`) character in your query. Since you don't have any keyword in your query, you don't need to use it.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM contentupload.film_person WHERE Person_id BETWEEN 100 AND 200";
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your dataadapter automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
  string query = "SELECT * FROM `contentupload`.`film_person WHERE Person_id BETWEEN '100' AND '200' `";
```

Have a look on :

```
`contentupload`.`film_person
```

There you go, error !!:

it should be :

```
contentupload.film_person
```

Final Query :

```
  string query = "SELECT * FROM contentupload.film_person WHERE Person_id BETWEEN '100' AND '200' ";
```